# Sum, Drug, Goo?

Tags: pattern, language, word-sequence

What comes next in the following sequence of words?

> Sum, Drug, Goo, ... ?

Notes to rule out incorrect methodologies:

- Once you find the right idea to answer, there is one unique and clearly correct answer, and nothing else will "arguably fit".
- > The sequence is infinite.

Comment: Well it looks like a regular vowelburger, a burger with two buns on bottom, a double burger missing its top bun...wait wrong riddle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the next word is

> Chunyi

Reasoning

> These are English transliterations of numbers in [Standard Tibetan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Tibetan) which are multiples of three. The next in the sequence is 12 which is given as **chunyi** (according to the linked page).

Comment: Hmm. Disappointingly trivia-y if so. [EDITED to add:] Must be right, though.

Comment: Yep, you got it!